# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method in plt.clabel

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, runtime-error, contour

I am trying to create a simple contour plot in Python. A sample of the .txt file I am using is this:
1,1,0.008935424499213696
2,1,0.0003330092004034668
3,1,0.0007237526588141918
4,1,0.009105708450078964
5,1,0.005323910620063543
6,1,0.002217665547505021
7,1,0.02252855896949768
8,1,0.01543859951198101
9,1,0.005959200672805309
10,1,0.003394557628780603
11,1,0.004915744531899691
12,1,0.7103423476219177
13,1,4.735919952392578
14,143,6.962272167205811
15,143,9.117818832397461
16,143,10.14690971374512
17,143,11.10696411132812
18,143,13.1904764175415
19,143,13.69217777252197
20,143,12.86547660827637
21,143,11.97461032867432
22,143,11.42048358917236
23,143,10.77302360534668
24,143,8.853728294372559
25,143,7.49812650680542
26,143,5.019758224487305
27,143,0.771071195602417

The code I am using is this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
# load values
X_dat, Y_dat, Z_dat = np.loadtxt('file.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',')

# Convert to numpy arrays
X, Y, Z, = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])
for i in range(len(X_dat)):
    X = np.append(X, X_dat[i])
    Y = np.append(Y, Y_dat[i])
    Z = np.append(Z, Z_dat[i])

# create x-y points to be used in heatmap
xi = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 290)
yi = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), 290)
# Interpolate for plotting
zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='cubic')

# Create the contour plot
levels = [0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
cp = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, levels, cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
plt.clabel(cp, fmt='%2.1f', inline='true', fontsize=12)
plt.title('Contour Plot')
plt.xlabel('x (cm)')
plt.ylabel('y (cm)')
```

but I get the following error:
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method
Triggered by plt.clabel.
How can I overcome this?

Thank you!

I think I have to convert the labels into integers, but I am not sure how...

Comment: input 'file.txt' is missing , where is griddata() defined ??

Comment: from scipy.interpolate import griddata ????

Comment: from scipy.interpolate import griddata yes

Comment: It works with me, only problem was getting the file.txt input that you didnt provide

Answer (score 0):

given `file.txt` :

```
0,    0,    0,
1000, 1000, 1000,
0,    1000, 1000,
20,   20,   500,
120,  120,  500,
10,   150,  200,
30,   450,  200
```

and your code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# load values
X_dat, Y_dat, Z_dat = np.loadtxt('file.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',' , usecols=(0,1, 2))

# Convert to numpy arrays
X, Y, Z, = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])
for i in range(len(X_dat)):
    X = np.append(X, X_dat[i])
    Y = np.append(Y, Y_dat[i])
    Z = np.append(Z, Z_dat[i])
    
    
print(X, Y, Z)

# create x-y points to be used in heatmap
xi = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 290)

# print(xi)
print(xi[None, : ])

yi = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), 290)
# Interpolate for plotting
zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='cubic')

# Create the contour plot
levels = [0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
cp = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, levels = levels, cmap='RdGy')
plt.colorbar()
# plt.show()
plt.clabel(cp, fmt='%2.1f', inline='true', fontsize=12)
plt.title('Contour Plot')
plt.xlabel('x (cm)')
plt.ylabel('y (cm)')


plt.show()
```

changed your line:

```
X_dat, Y_dat, Z_dat = np.loadtxt('file.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',')
```

into :

```
X_dat, Y_dat, Z_dat = np.loadtxt('file.txt', unpack=True, delimiter=',' , usecols=(0,1, 2))
```

I get:

[image: imaage output]

Can't really try to help you without your input `file.txt`  file

using your data reformatted as:

```
1,1,0.008935424499213696 
2,1,0.0003330092004034668 
3,1,0.0007237526588141918 
4,1,0.009105708450078964 
5,1,0.005323910620063543 
6,1,0.002217665547505021 
7,1,0.02252855896949768 
8,1,0.01543859951198101 
9,1,0.005959200672805309 
10,1,0.003394557628780603 
11,1,0.004915744531899691 
12,1,0.7103423476219177 
13,1,4.735919952392578 
14,143,6.962272167205811 
15,143,9.117818832397461 
16,143,10.14690971374512 
17,143,11.10696411132812 
18,143,13.1904764175415 
19,143,13.69217777252197 
20,143,12.86547660827637 
21,143,11.97461032867432 
22,143,11.42048358917236 
23,143,10.77302360534668 
24,143,8.853728294372559 
25,143,7.49812650680542 
26,143,5.019758224487305 
27,143,0.771071195602417
```

I get:

[image: new output]

but I prefer the one I get using:

```
cp = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels = levels, cmap='RdGy')
```

that looks like:

[image: using counturf]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I added a  small sample of the .txt file.

Comment: not sure it is what you were looking for